# Caching the data from a database

Tags: database, caching

I am having 100,000 rows coming from database, which is the data viewed by different users.
Is it a good idea to keep 100,000 rows in cache or is it good idea to keep the data each and every time from database?
I am asking because the data is 100,000 rows.Any pointers?

Comment: What environment is this? In any case i would suggest splitting the results if possible. Nobody likes 100000 rows going up and down through the network. What will the administrator say?

Comment: What happens if it's only once a day ? What happens if each row consists of one integer ? What will he say then ? I don't think there's enough info here to make any such assertions

Answer (score 2):

As with most questions of this nature, you need to determine *if* performance is an issue *before* looking at such solutions. [As Knuth says](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization):

> Premature optimisation is the root of all evil

Otherwise you're going to expend energy/time etc. solving an issue that may not be an issue at all...

Answer (score 0):

Dont get all the records at a time. Two solutions:

1. Get records in chunks
2. Accept different criteria from user and get the records accordingly